# PHP/SQL Inserting to DB using form "Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" but can't figure out why count doesn't match

Tags: php, sql, forms, post, insert

TABLE COLUMNS
theid
sirename
yob
color
breed
owner
approved

FORM TO GATHER INFO TO INSERT INTO DB

```
<form method='post' action='nominateasire2.php'>
The ID: <input type='text' name='theid'><br><br>
Sire Name: <input type='text' name='sirename'><br><br>
YOB: <input type='text' name='yob'><br><br>
Color: <input type='text' name='color'><br><br>
Breed: <input type='text' name='breed'><br><br>
Owner: <input type='text' name='owner'><br><br>
<input type='submit' value='Nominate'>
</form>
```

PHP TO INSERT INFO FROM FORM INTO DB

```
$sql="INSERT INTO nominatedsires (theid,sirename,yob,color,breed,owner,approved)
VALUES ('$_POST[theid]','$_POST[sirename]','$_POST[yob]',
'$_POST[color]','$_POST[breed]','$_POST[owner]','$_POST[owner]','no')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
```

When using the form I get the error **Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**. When I go through PHPmyAdmin and input the data it all works fine so there isn't an error on the backend (value length/type/etc.) I can't figure out what the issue with my code is. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this. Adding `$_POST` data directly to a query is **extremely** dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have '$_POST[owner]', twice.  Remove one of them and you should be ok.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. That is definitely a face palm moment. Works great now.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra column in your list of values. `$_POST[owner]` is there twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your previous code is:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO nominatedsires (theid,sirename,yob,color,breed,owner,approved)
VALUES ('$_POST[theid]','$_POST[sirename]','$_POST[yob]',
'$_POST[color]','$_POST[breed]','$_POST[owner]','$_POST[owner]','no')";
```

This is the correct code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO nominatedsires (theid,sirename,yob,color,breed,owner,approved)
VALUES ('$_POST[theid]','$_POST[sirename]','$_POST[yob]',
'$_POST[color]','$_POST[breed]','$_POST[owner]','no')";
```